# Why won't ml-auto move nav items to the right

Tags: html, css

My nav items stay to the left, even with ml-auto. I looked at some questions on here but I haven't found something that fixes my issue. I even followed a video and I can't see anything conflicting.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="navbar">
  <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" id="navbar-logo">Development</span>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Which browser is used?

Comment: Google Chrome..

Comment: Assuming you're using Bootstrap the `ml-auto` class will do nothing in this context since it has a parent inside the `navbar` container which is the flex element, also you have a few unclosed tags.

Comment: you could use flex and justify it to right.

Comment: What is `.ml-auto` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap 5, ml & mr are replaced with ms & me respectively.

Everything left & right has been changed to start & end

Forgive me if this is of no help. I am a noob at this, but just encountered and resolved the same issue, myself.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ml-auto with ms-auto. In Bootstrap 5, ml is replaced with ms which means margin start.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30766585)